# Count instances of a value in a certain index of sublists within a list, but only once per list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I have data similar to this:

```
[[1, 1, 4]], [[1, 2, 4], [1, 7, 4]], [[2, 2, 4]]
```

I am iterating like this:

```
count = 0
for list in lists:
    for sublist in list:
        if sublist[2] == 4:
            count += 1
print(count)
```

The output always ends up being 4.

I want to iterate through all 3 lists of sublists, count the time that "4" is in the third index of a sublist. However, in the second list I only want it counted once, not twice. So the value returned should be 3, not 4.

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to achieve - you're describing the "how" and "what" but not the "why". If it's arbitrary, you can replace the iteration of `for sublist in list:` with getting the sublist in`list[0]` and it should "fix" your issue.

Comment: there's a few ways you could handle this, with additional checking if each sublist contains a `4` and increment `count` if *at least one* sublist contains a `4`, which may require a few more checks and error handling, but the quick fix as ^alfasin mentioned (change lines 3 and 4 to: `for sublist in list[0]: if sublist == 4:` will give you returned value of `3`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply fix it by breaking out of the innermost loop if you found one `sublist` that has a `4` in the third position. That basically checks if any `sublist` fulfills your condition:

```
count = 0
for lst in lists:
    for sublist in lst:
        if sublist[2] == 4:
            count += 1
            break             # just added that line
print(count)
# 3
```

I also replaced the variable name `list` with `lst` because it would otherwise shadow the built-in name [`list`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-list).

This could also be written as:

```
>>> sum(any(sublist[2] == 4 for sublist in lst) for lst in lists)
3
```

Or in case you want to check that all `sublist`s fulfill the condition replace `any` with `all`:

```
>>> sum(all(sublist[2] == 4 for sublist in lst) for lst in lists)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def has4(lol):
   for lst in lol:
       if lst[2] == 4:
           return True
   return False

lists = [[1, 1, 4]], [[1, 2, 4], [1, 7, 4]], [[2, 2, 4]]

count = sum(map(has4, lists))
```

First we define a predicate which returns True for matched items.  Then we use `map()` to transform the input into a boolean sequence of matched/not-matched.  Then we sum, taking advantage of the fact that True counts as 1 and False is 0.